# Array vacío cuando se hace el llamado Express js y React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base-de-datos, express

Tengo un problema que cuando le doy a poder ver la lista de materiales este no me suelta por consola un array vacio pero si lo pongo manualmente por la url si me suelta la data en json, estos son las porciones de codigo.
Lo que tengo hasta ahora es lo que he intentado hasta el momento solo muestra que encuentra el array que los datos son ingresados, pero al momento de obtener el array y la conexion con las tablas este solo muestra un array vacio[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
app.get("/home/fabricacion/:id_fabricacion/materiales", async (req, res) => {
  const numero_tablero = req.params.numero_tablero;

  try {
    // Consultar la base de datos para obtener los materiales asociados a la fabricación
    const materialesSQL = "SELECT * FROM tb_fabricacion_materiales WHERE id_fabricacion IN (SELECT id_fabricacion FROM tb_fabricacion WHERE numero_tablero = ?)";
    const materialesValues = [numero_tablero];
    const materialesResult = await db.queryAsync(materialesSQL, materialesValues);
    const materiales = materialesResult.map((material) => ({
      id: material.id,
      nombre: material.nombre,
      cantidad: material.cantidad,
      // Agrega otras propiedades según tu esquema de base de datos
    }));

    console.log('Datos obtenidos correctamente:', materiales); // Agrega este log para depurar

    // Devolver los materiales
    return res.status(200).json({ materiales });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al obtener materiales:', error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error interno del servidor' });
  }
});
```

```js
app.get("/home/fabricacion/:id_fabricacion/materiales", async (req, res) => {
  const numero_tablero = req.params.numero_tablero;

  try {
    // Consultar la base de datos para obtener los materiales asociados a la fabricación
    const materialesSQL = "SELECT * FROM tb_fabricacion_materiales WHERE id_fabricacion IN (SELECT id_fabricacion FROM tb_fabricacion WHERE numero_tablero = ?)";
    const materialesValues = [numero_tablero];
    const materialesResult = await db.queryAsync(materialesSQL, materialesValues);
    const materiales = materialesResult.map((material) => ({
      id: material.id,
      nombre: material.nombre,
      cantidad: material.cantidad,
      // Agrega otras propiedades según tu esquema de base de datos
    }));

    console.log('Datos obtenidos correctamente:', materiales); // Agrega este log para depurar

    // Devolver los materiales
    return res.status(200).json({ materiales });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al obtener materiales:', error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error interno del servidor' });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo porque tienes `/:id_fabricacion/` y luego al momento de obtener los parámetros obtienes `req.params.numero_tablero`, si cambias eso creo que solucionarías el problema, si persiste entonces revisa que la consulta SQL regrese los datos que esperas.

Como bonus podrías hacer un `JOIN` en lugar de una subconsulta así como dese desestructurar ciertas partes., adjunto código:

```
app.get("/home/fabricacion/:id_fabricacion/materiales", async (req, res) => {
  const {id_fabricacion} = req.params;

  try {
    const materialesSQL = `
      SELECT a.* 
      FROM tb_fabricacion_materiales a
      JOIN tb_fabricacion b ON a.id_fabricacion = b.id_fabricacion
      WHERE b.numero_tablero = ?
    `;
    const materialesValues = [id_fabricacion];
    const materialesResult = await db.queryAsync(materialesSQL, materialesValues);
    const materiales = materialesResult.map(({id, nombre, cantidad}) => ({
      id,
      nombre,
      cantidad,
    }));

    console.log('Datos obtenidos correctamente:', materiales);

    return res.status(200).json({ materiales });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al obtener materiales:', error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: `Error interno del servidor: ${error.message}` });
  }
});
```

Comment: gracias por responder, al final lo dejé asi y ya funciona   SELECT
    tb_fabricacion_materiales.nombre,
    tb_fabricacion_materiales.cantidad
  FROM
    tb_fabricacion_materiales
  INNER JOIN
    tb_fabricacion
  ON
    tb_fabricacion_materiales.id_fabricacion_materiales = tb_fabricacion.id_fabricacion
  WHERE
    tb_fabricacion_materiales.id_fabricacion_materiales = ?; Saludos.